# How to delete new'd arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, new-operator, unityscript, delete-operator

I'm using Unity, so this is technically UnityScript but I assume the built-in arrays work the same way. I have an array I create thusly:

```
var room:roomInfo[,,];
room=new roomInfo[5,5,5];
```

What's the deleting syntax? Simply doing `delete room;` or `delete room[,,];` doesn't seem to work. After deleting it I need to do this:

```
room=new roomInfo[10,10,10];
```

Seems like a ridiculously simple question but I get confused about these things and forget, and I couldn't find anything on Google (because I couldn't work out what to search).

Comment: JS automatically manages memory for you. It means you don't need to (and cannot) delete it explicitly.

Comment: @zerkms So... if I need to recreate the array as a larger array... what, I just do `room=new roomInfo[sizex,sizey,sizez];` without explicitly deleting the old `room` array? That won't cause memory leaks?

Comment: @zerkms it's unityscript not JS, in JS this syntax doesn't even exist.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What syntax doesn't exist?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I know that - my comment was about JS specifically since it has it in tags.

Comment: In JavaScript, you can't do `new roomInfo[5,5,5]`, this would ignore the first two fives (comma operator), and `new` whatever `roomInfo` is holding at index 5 (as property lookup).

Comment: If you want to increase the size of the array - it is preferable not to assign it a new address but to let unity resize it for you using System.Array.Resize - but really - use a list.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a thousand times better than Unity Answers! The same question I posted here has been on UA for many hours and only has a pathetic attempt at an answer, whereas on SO I get tens of comments and two answers within 5 minutes of posting :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Why is that preferable? And also, I attempted to use Lists but it became extremely complicated because I was creating a List inside a List inside a List and resizing the array was a nightmare. Speed (hopefully) won't be an issue with manually recreating the array to resize it :)

Comment: @Clonkex what do these 3 parameters mean in the dimensions (the 10*10*10)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What do you mean? `room=new roomInfo[10,10,10];` creates a three-dimensional array where each dimension is size 10. Someone mentioned that it's UnityScript-only syntax and not JS-compatible.

Comment: @Clonkex right, but why is the 'roomInfo" array 3d in the first place? What does each dimension represent?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Each dimension represents a 3D position, effectively. My game world is built around a 3D grid of "rooms". But what difference does it make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do it, as UnityScript already does it for you ([Automatic Memory Management](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html)). But if you still prefer your own way to do, use this:

```
room = null;
```

And after this, you can initialise it to:

```
room = new roomInfo[10,10,10];
```

So the full code would be:

```
room = null;
room = new roomInfo[10,10,10];
```

Comment: Do I _need_ to do `room=null;`?

Comment: @Clonkex I would say no. The reason is: *The keyword null, is a nonexistant value. It can be assigned to a variable, or used to test whether a variable has a value.* As in the docs, I have considered your statement to remove the value.

Comment: So it's just there to explicitly show (to the programmer) that the array is no longer in use?

Comment: @Clonkex Yup! Precisely.

Comment: Thanks! Your post is excellent and I'll accept it just as soon as Stack Overflow lets me (5 minutes) :)

Answer (score 1):

Unity Script is (as JavaScript) using Garbage Collection to automatically free up unused memory.

An element is released if there is no variable pointing at the object. The garbage collector is aware of any variable that *could* hold a pointer to your array and determines if there are any variables pointing to that array.

If no variable points to your array it will be marked to be released.

> When an object, string or array is created, the memory required to store it is allocated from a central pool called the heap. When the item is no longer in use, the memory it once occupied can be reclaimed and used for something else. [...] Nowadays, runtime systems like Unity’s Mono engine manage memory for you automatically.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html

Comment: That doesn't really help me (the quote at least - haven't had time to read the entire article yet) because I don't know what constitutes "no longer in use".

Comment: @Clonkex If you don't have a reference to the array (a variable pointing to that array) the array will be released.

Comment: @idmean "the array will be released" --- this is not entirely correct. The object *might be* released at some point in time after (if ever).

Comment: @zerkms Of course. But if one has never heard before of automatic memory management, it might not be the most important information *when* the garbage collector is invoked.

Comment: @idmean indeed. And to be even more pedantic: the standard does not define garbage collection process at all. So an arbitrary ES implementation may not even have one :-)